# Place multiple images at different places on screen in CSS at some defined coordinatess

Tags: html, css, image

Here is a set  four images to  be placed on different places on screen i have mentioned the coordinates in the code. 
Actually, I want my images top left coordinate positioned as in the code.But it's not working out.
so could you help out please in finding out the error?

```css
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#imagegroup1{
 display:inline;
 positon:absolute;
 top:160px;/*pos
 left:690px;
 
 }
 #imagegroup2{float:left;
 display:inline;
 positon:static;
 top:160px;
 left:1000px;
 }
#imagegroup3{

 display:inline;
 positon:absolute;
 top:360px;
 left:690px;
 
 }
#imagegroup4{
 display:inline;
 positon:absolute;
 top:360px;
 left:1000px;
 
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id ="imagegroup1"><img src="img1.jpg" height="180px" width="270px"/></div>
<div class="imagegroup2"><img src="img2.jpg" height="180" width="270"/></div>
<img id="imagegroup3" src="img3..jpg" height="180" width="270"/>
<img id="imagegroup4" src="img4.jpg" height="180" width="270"/>

</body>
```

Comment: There is a partial comment (`/*pos`) on line 4 of your CSS. You should complete (`*/`) or delete it.

Comment: hey it came by chance!!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go about this is to use a grid from a css framework (Bootstrap, foundation etc). Using Float isn't recommended for this type of positioning. If you don't wish to use a css framework you could use a table.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Image 1</td>
    <td>Image 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Image 3</td>
    <td>Image 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You could easily reposition everything using this structure. And it will be much easier to implement a responsive design.

Comment: in this way i just need to position the table's top coordinates right!

Comment: Using absolute positioning yes. In your CSS add position: absolute; top: SomeNumberpx; left: someNumber px.

Comment: Upon further review, it seems this should answer the original question better.